# Berry–Esseen like bounds for empirical distribution

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Consider a sequence of i.i.d. continuous random variables $\{X_j\}_j$ taking values in $[0,1]$. Define the empirical distribution function
$$Y^n_t=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n1_{X_j \le t}\textit{, } 0\le t\le 1. $$
If we denote the distribution function of $X_j$ by $F$ then I would like to show that if we let $V^n:=n^\frac 12 (Y^n-F)$, then $\{V^n\}_n$ is tight in $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

I have tried using Theorem 2.7.3 in Bilingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures which implies (since $V^n_0=0$) that $\{V^n\}_n$ will be tight if
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{s<t \le 1, |s-t|\le \delta}   |V^n_t-V^n_s|\ge \epsilon \right)=0, $$
for all $\epsilon>0$, which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{\delta\to 0}\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \sup_{s<t \le 1, |s-t|\le \delta} |\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j=1}^n1_{s<X_j\le t}-\sqrt{n}(F(t)-F(s))|\ge \epsilon \right)=0.$$
So what I need is a Berry–Esseen like result for empirical distributions, is there any such result? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally found an answer here:
[https://math.mit.edu/~rmd/465/edf-ks.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ermd/465/edf-ks.pdf)